# Which numeric type should I choose for my courses?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a table IN `Postgresql` with course

```
15-455
15-721
```

and so on.
How to represent them when creating table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're not straightforward numeric values (which they're not because they contain a hyphen), then you should just use the `text` type.  If the numbers you shared represent 2 separate columns, then an int4 type would cover them.